# create a calendar out of Access information

Tags: ms-access

How can I create a calendar / task agenda out of information in an Access database? I've got a db of information on cases that need to be followed up with. I'd like to export an agenda that I can track based on follow up dates.

Thanks

Comment: What is your environment ? Outlook ? Exchange ? Sharepoint ?

Comment: How do you see this happening? For example, you can update an Outlook calendar from Access without too much code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is a simple export you can use the [OutputTo](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/export-macro.html) Macro command to export to various file formats.

The output file can be based on most access objects E.G. you can create a query that selects the information you want and use this query in the OutputTo command.

Note this can also be achieved using [code](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/docmd_outputto_example.htm).

the macro / VBA function can be attached to a command button to automate so that you can export at the click of a button.

I have used this technique in a database I have built;

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) standard. There is a [PHP class](http://www.kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/) available for it that generates such standards. Maybe Access (which is VB I think?) also has some of these scripts. But the thing is with looking for 3rd party libs, that they provibe maybe more info than you want.